# Usar dato de otra clase

Tags: java

Tengo este método:

```
    public String comprovarLogin(String usuari, String contrasenya){
    final String metode = "comprovarLogin";
    String ret = null;
    try{         
        //Preparem els arguments del mÃ¨tode compovarLogin
        Map<String,String> args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("usuari",usuari);
        args.put("contrasenya",contrasenya);
        //Fem la crida al mètode per obtenir-ne la resposta
        SoapObject respostaSoap = usarWebService(metode,args);
        //Retornem el valor de "authId"   
        System.out.println(respostaSoap.getPrimitiveProperty("authId"));


    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        ret = "ERROR_CRIDA";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

en la clase WbServiceCalls

El tema es que desde otra clase llamada Xxxxxxx

Hago lo siguiente:

```
     WebServiceCalls calls = new WebServiceCalls();
         System.out.println(calls.comprovarLogin(usuari, usuariContrasenya));
```

Llamo al método comprovarLogin y le paso dos valores.

Hasta aquí perfecto.
Pero me interesaría poder usar la variable respostaSoap.getPrimiteProperty("authId") de la clase webserviceCalls para hacer cosas con ella desde la clase xxxxxxx.

Como puedo hacerlo?

La idea es hacer un if/else para comprobar que el valor authId sea por ejemplo el nombre "Dani".

Gracias.

PD: Mi idea sería hacer algo así:

```
     WebServiceCalls calls = new WebServiceCalls();
         System.out.println(calls.comprovarLogin(usuari, usuariContrasenya));
//comprobar authId
if (Authid.equalsIgnoreCase("Dani"){
bla bla bla
{
}else{
bla bla 
}
```

Comment: Sé que es en catalán (y por tanto correcto), pero ver *comprobar* con v duele ;)

Comment: jajaja si es catalán! :P y si es cierto duele si no lo sabes! xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me hace curioso que devuelvas null cuando todo va bien y un mensaje de error que realmente no dice nada especial cuando el login falla. ¿Por qué no devuelves lo que necesitas?:

```
public SoapObject comprovarLogin(String usuari, String contrasenya){
    final String metode = "comprovarLogin";
    SoapObject respostaSoap = null;
    try{         
        //Preparem els arguments del mÃ¨tode compovarLogin
        Map<String,String> args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("usuari",usuari);
        args.put("contrasenya",contrasenya);
        //Fem la crida al mètode per obtenir-ne la resposta
        SoapObject respostaSoap = usarWebService(metode,args);
        //Retornem el valor de "authId"   
        System.out.println(respostaSoap.getPrimitiveProperty("authId"));


    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return respostaSoap;
}
```

El uso sería algo como:

```
WebServiceCalls calls = new WebServiceCalls();
SoapObject resposta = calls.comprovarLogin(usuari, usuariContrasenya));
if (resposta == null) {
    //error
} else {
    String authId = resposta.getPrimitiveProperty("authId"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: gracias lo apunto para otros casos que pueda pasarme! ^^

Comment: Estoy probando tu forma pero respostaSoap.GetPrimitive no existe. :(

Comment: @MontseMkd Arreglado, una errata al copiar de tu código: dentro del método se llama respostaSoap y fuera lo llamé simplemente resposta

Comment: me da error la variable authId no se puede convertir soapObject en String.. he intentado modificar e iniciar la variable autId como Soap y tampoco.. T_T

Comment: ya esta iniciada como Object y me funciona!!!

Comment: @MontseMkd Yo me fie de tu código, no conozco la clase SoapObject ni qué tiene... como lo ví dentro de un System.out.println asumí un String :P

Answer (score 1):

Te comento...

Hay varias formas de realizar de hacer lo que comentas, pero para lo que deseas hacer te puede ayudar esto:

1. Asumimos que tienes dos clases, en esté ejemplo a una la nombre **Actual** y a la otra **Other**.
2. En la clase **Actual**, crea una variable pública statica `public static string authId = "";` esto te permite acceder a ella desde otra clase, recordando que la clase debe de ser pública. 
   **Nota:** recordar que las variables staticas tienen tiempo de vida que se extiende durante toda la ejecución del programa.
   Ahora asigna el valor que desees a esa variable para que persista durante la ejecución del programa, ejemplo: `authId = respostaSoap.getPrimitiveProperty("authId");`.
3. Ahora, nada más haces uso de ella en la clase **Other**, ejemplo: `String strAuthId  = Actual.authId;` o utiliza un método getter.

Te comparto tu código con lo antes mencionado:

```
public class Actual
{
        public static String authId = "";

        public String comprobarLogin(String usuari, String contrasenya)
        {

            final String metode = "comprovarLogin";
            String ret = "";//no entiendo porque le tienes null acá

            try{                            
                Map<String,String> args = new HashMap<>();
                args.put("usuari",usuari);
                args.put("contrasenya",contrasenya);
                SoapObject respostaSoap = usarWebService(metode,args);  
                System.out.println(respostaSoap.getPrimitiveProperty("authId"));

                authId = respostaSoap.getPrimitiveProperty("authId").toString(); //por ejemplo

            }

            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                ret = "ERROR_CRIDA";
            }

            return ret;
        }
}

public class Other
{
    String strAuthId  = Actual.authId;

    WebServiceCalls calls = new WebServiceCalls();
    System.out.println(calls.comprobarLogin(usuari, usuariContrasenya));
    //comprobar authId
    if (strAuthId.equalsIgnoreCase("Dani"))
    {
        //Code
    {
    }
    else
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Como te comentaba al principio, tienes varias formas de hacerlo, espero os sirva para que tomes una idea,

Suerte...

Comment: no me funciona     private readonly string strAuthId  = Actual.authId;
 

el readonly me sale error e idem con el strAuthId que hago mal?

Comment: Ya lo edite, readonly  es una propiedad que no pertenece a Java. `public final String title;` este sería el equivalente en Java, aunque no es propio del lenguaje. Lo podes realizar con un getter pero ahorita debería funcionarte.

Comment: gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: De nada, seguí escribiendo código :D .

Comment: me da error ... es decir me da valor null T_T

Comment: el problema principal es que resposta soap es un SoapObject.. i si modifico la clase entonces me peta.. a´si que sigo igual :(

Comment: El problema de esta solución es que no es *thread safe*, todos los objetos comparten la variable estática

Comment: No entiendo bien tu código, pero tienes allí que retorne **null** no se porque. Yo por esa razon lo deje así, en lo que respecta al SoapObejt que mencionas realiza un toString(); revisa el código.

Comment: Como el quería evaluar el usuario, le di un ejemplo, como lo podía hacer. Debe de capturar el usuario y almacenarlo en la variable.